# Как извлечь корень 5 степени из числа

Tags: pascal

Задача такая:
надо вычислить значение функции с корнем 5 степени из числа

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Чтобы получить корень степени `n`, нужно возвести число в степень `1/n`.

```
function root(a, b: extended) : extended;
begin
  root := exp((1.0 / b) * ln (a));
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

Я практически любую степень считал так (небольшой пример):

**Exp(b*Ln(a))**

```
Var
   a, b, c: Real;

Begin
     Write('a = '); ReadLn(a); // число
     Write('b = '); ReadLn(b); // степень (корень 5-ой степени - степень 1/5)
     WriteLn('a^b = ', Exp(b*Ln(a)):9:3); 
     ReadLn;
End.
```